# Prevent object from being moved by garbage collector in F#

Tags: pointers, f#, garbage-collection

In C# it es easy to pin an object to the place where it currently is stored using the keyword "fixed". Here is an example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx):

```
unsafe static void TestMethod()
{

    // assume class Point { public int x, y; }
    // pt is a managed variable, subject to garbage collection.
    Point pt = new Point();

    // Using fixed allows the address of pt members to be
    // taken, and "pins" pt so it isn't relocated.

    fixed (int* p = &pt.x)
    {
        *p = 1;
    }        

}
```

How can this be done in F#?

Comment: Given that F# has no analogous "unsafe" mode - what would be the point? - Or are you interacting with unmanaged code?

Comment: I am using the NativePtr module for manipulating buffers. First I create a block array like this: `let structureElement : byte[,] = Array2D.create 5 5 0uy`. Then I get a pointer to this Array: `let pStructElem = &&structureElement.[0,0]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use [GCHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx) with type *Pinned*